# The Chrome window not able to establish websocket connection when scripting in selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, selenium-chromedriver, testng

Error:

> unable to establish websocket connection to
> http://localhost:1615/devtools/browser/0089cfa1-17f9-4fce-a8fc-88c3b4703886
> build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'

Code:

```
public class SeleniumTest {
    
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest  
    public void setUp()  
    {
 
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```